# symfony 1.4 forms - how to set value of one field while submiting the form?

Tags: forms, symfony1, save, symfony-1.4

how can I do this?

I'm trying:

```
$this->form->getObject()->setWebsiteid($website);

$this->form->setDefault('websiteid', $website);

$request->setParameter('websiteid', $website);
```

none from above doesn't work

my code:

```
$this->form = new sfGuardRegisterForm();

if ($request->isMethod('post'))
{
  $website=new Website();
  $website->save();

  $this->form->bind($request->getParameter($this->form->getName()));
  if ($this->form->isValid())
  {
    /* here I try do that */
    $this->form->getObject()->setWebsiteid($website);
    /* here I try do that end */

    $user = $this->form->save();
    $this->getUser()->signIn($user);

    $this->redirect('@homepage');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `websiteid` part of your `User` model ?

Do you use the widget of `websiteid` in your form ?

You can add the value after the save:

```
$user = $this->form->save();
$user->setWebsiteid($website);
$user->save();
```

But the first solution seems ok to me..

Comment: This really isn't the best approach. Logic should be part of the form save() method via doSave() override. This way everything related to the form is within the same transaction, and also keeps the calling code lean.